# datetime usage for pagination

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

I want to output the datetime as a HTTP GET parameter like this

```
 2011-04-11 12:09:21.366575
```

Instead the following output appears

```
 April 11, 2011, 12:09 p.m.
```

This change took place with an upgrade of seemingly other components so I don't understand why it changed. The code is the same and what differs is the environment

```
datetime.strptime(bookmark[:-7], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Can you explain what I need to do to get the data on the format like the first? I am passing on the bookmark parameter to do pagination like mentioned in [this](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/paging.html) article.

Thank you

UPDATE: The code I got is

```
bookmark = self.request.get("bookmark") if self.request.get('bookmark') else self.request.get("b")
category = self.request.get('cg')
q = self.request.get('q').encode("utf-8")
w = self.request.get('q')
cg = self.request.get('cg')
t = self.request.get('t') 
f = self.request.get('f')
if bookmark:
  bookmark = datetime.strftime(bookmark[:-7], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  
else:       
  bookmark = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
if cg and not t and not q and not f:
    entities = Entity.all().filter("category =", cg).filter("modified >", timeline).filter("published =", True).filter("modified <=", bookmark )...
```

Comment: I think you are missing something here. The code and strptime format has no relation with the output you are getting.

Comment: Your question does not contain any code or whatever in order to make your question in some way coherent. Another try please...

Comment: I tried to clarify this mysterious error I get from following the code in an article.

Comment: The time format you're getting as output still doesn't match the strptime statement - the output includes a fractions-of-seconds field that the strptime call doesn't. Are you sure this is the code that's actually being called?

Comment: I include more code now.

Comment: I think you are still looking at the wrong piece of code.  I'm assuming that you just replaced strptime with strftime based on my answer, if that's the case the original intent of the code you've posted is to convert a string representation of date time into an actual datetime object for use in the query.  It has nothing to do with output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datetime.strptime returns a datetime object from a string (given a formatting parameter).  It sounds like you are looking to do the opposite (return a formatted string from a datetime object), which would be datetime.strftime.  Using "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" as your formatting in conjunction with strftime should give you the output you are looking for.